# Certain LS results unreadable with Solarized theme on Windows 10 Linux subsystem

Tags: linux, bash, colors, themes, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After fiddling around for a while, I was able to get Bash on Windows to use the Solarized color scheme via the method discussed in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/60da1u/solarized_colors_for_vim_in_bash_on_windows_works/) thread. It even allows me to have vim switch over to the light theme with the proper adjustment to my `.vimrc` file. However, since making this change, I now have the following hideous, unreadable color contrast with certain results when running `ls`:

[image: This cyan on yellow-green is harsh on the eyes and difficult to understand]

Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix this without altering the colors in the properties panel again--trying to change the usual config files that would work on an actual Linux machine achieved nothing--and doing so would potentially undermine other aspects of the color scheme.

Comment: What happens after `export LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:"fi=40;37"` ?

Answer (score 2):

Verify that you don't have a file `~/.dircolors`.  If you do, just modify it.
If not, run `dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors` This generates a default dircolors config file for you.

Open this file in vim.  The entries will be color-coded.  You can modify the ones you find offensive.  This is probably OTHER_WRITABLE.  I personally changed it to 37;42, which is still bad, but readable.

Oh, and you almost certainly already have something in your ~/.bashrc or .~/zshrc that's already doing this, but if not, you'll want to add a line like:

```
dircolors -b ~/.dircolors
```

to the appropriate file.  The typical pre-existing one looks like this:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
```

Also, there is this, however it does not fix the problem with OTHER_WRITABLE sticky/non-sticky directories:

```
https://github.com/huyz/dircolors-solarized
```